# Is there a Chaotic Evil God of the Sea in the Forgotten Realms?

Tags: forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

I'm running a narrative that revolves around consumption, centered around three factions that worship evil gods based around that theme. I have a group of gnolls and cultists that worship Yeenoghu, the Ceaseless Hunger, and a group of Yuan-Ti that worship Dendar, the World Eater. The third faction is a band of pirates who should thematically worship some god of the sea, but I've been unable to find one that I find to be a perfect fit.

Ideally they would be chaotic evil and have some aspect of consumption in their portfolio, such as "the swallowing sea", "the endless depths" or the erosion of land. Panzuriel is the best fit I've been able to find so far, being a minor god of evil sea creatures and murder. Is Panzuriel the best fit for this profile, or does a water god of consumption exist in the Forgotten Realms?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Panzuriel is an alias of Umberlee, actually. [See here](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Umberlee)

> Umberlee had worshipers among krakens, sahuagin and other evil sea creatures, even though a few of them worshiped her through her alias, Panzuriel

One of her titles is 'Queen of the Depths', but her portfolio is listed as Currents, Oceans, Sea Winds, and Waves. That weresharks and krakens are among her worshipers lends some 'eaty-ness' to her to my eye.

More obscure, and apparently more limited in worshipers is [Sekolah](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Sekolah), a sahuagin deity known as The Great Shark, The Joyful Hunter, and The Caller from the Depths. If your pirates are sahuagin (or malenti, consider the amphibious template from *Stormwrack* to not have to worry about breathing, for -2 dex) then they could worship him.

Both of these deities can be found in *Faiths and Pantheons* as well.

Comment: Odd that they were listed separately in the resources I was using to do my research. This is a fitting answer, but I'd like to wait until tomorrow to accept it, in case a better fit can be found.

Comment: @THiebert No worries; I'm not invested in this one very much as you can see. There're not many (any) other CE (most likely to be devourers) that I've found as yet.