# Is there a God of the Sea other than Umberlee in the Forgotten Realms?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

In the near future I'll be taking part in the campaign of Waterdeep: Dragon heist. I'm currently working on my character for it, which will most likely be a human Tempest Cleric with the Sailor background. The problem I face is deciding which deity grants the cleric their abilities.

To my understanding, Waterdeep is a big city that's highly dependent on its sea trade. I'd therefore expect there to be a God(dess) of the Sea with quite a large following around town, but I can't find one. The only two gods of the Sea I can find, are Umberlee (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100295/forgotten-realms-god-of-the-sea)) and Deep Sashelas. The former is Chaotic Evil and hated throughout the world, while the latter is an elven god. Neither of those seems a logical choice.

Am I missing a more major God of the Sea in this world? Which god would seafarers and those dependent on their work worship in Waterdeep?

*Edit:* [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106587/is-there-a-good-aligned-tempest-domain-deity) provides a good overview of non-evil gods with the Tempest domain. Even though my question came up during creation of a Tempest Cleric and I appreciate the focus on that part, answers don't need to restrict to the domain; I'm also interested in gods without it. Not just out of curiosity, but also to get a rough idea about the theological context this cleric will be operating in.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Valkur

[Valkur](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Valkur) appears to be the only good-aligned Faerunian deity of the sea, though I admit I don't know much about him. He's an exarch/demigod/lesser deity attached to the war god Tempus. Apparently he's chaotic good, has Tempest as one of his domains, and may have once been a mortal.

### Selune

Selune is not a sea deity as such, but as the goddess of the moon and night sky, she has a connection to tides and navigators. From those, she acts as a patron to sailors in general. However, calm Selune seems like a poor fit for the wild Tempest domain.

### Worship doesn't always mean approval

Just for the record, historically, worship of deities has sometimes been in the form of propitiation -- that is to say, offerings to appease a dangerous and chaotic deity in hopes that they will not crush you like a bug. A sailor might technically worship Amaunator while on land, but also make some sort of offering to Umberlee before setting out on a voyage to ask that she not sink his ship.

It might be more difficult to justify that in the context of a cleric, but if there are rites to be performed, there's probably somebody to do those rites. If that means presenting a hand-carved model of your ship to a kind of creepy dude who claims to have a direct line to the Wavemother so he can burn it and scatter the ashes on the sea, well, that's the cost of maybe getting a pass on the whole 'sunk by a freak hurricane' thing.

Today we often think of a priest as the hand of their god, the manifestation of its will in the world, but that's a kind of Christianized version of the concept that assumes gods are *inherently good*. Historically, being "the one who stands between the people and the gods" meant that in both senses -- both the connection and the shield. If rubbing up against that kind of entity means the priest gets a little weird (i.e. chaotic) and might not be entirely safe to be around, well, it's a dirty job that somebody has to do.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The second part provides an interesting option I hadn't thought of. I think this character will be that creepy dude.

Comment: Zeboim from Dragonlance is much the same way. People don't worship her out of love, they worship her out of fear. Many of her clerics aren't there to advance her religion as much as spread information about how to stay safe at sea and avoid her wrath. Since she'd rather be placated than wrathful (usually), these good clerics are more than welcome to do what they do.

Answer (score 8):

### Amaunator, Keeper of the Sun

Based on your character description, the most thematically appropriate Faerun deity is going to be [Amaunator](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/welcome-to-the-realms#Amaunator), who is described in the *Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide* (p. 24):

> Farmers and travelers beseech him when they pray for rain or sun, as do any others looking for a favorable change in the weather.

As a sailor and cleric of the tempest, Amaunator, the god in charge of the weather, is right on brand for you.

Comment: While this is true don't sailors tend to at least pray to umberlee? Having a cleric to placate her seems pretty natural despite her alignment

Comment: @SeriousBri Yes, but generally *not* because they like her. There’s a reason she’s called *The Bitch Queen*.

Comment: I upvoted this, I think it is a good, general answer, given that a more specific god for a good PC cleric with a seafaring background is missing.

Answer (score 7):

There's a list of deities connected to the sea / ocean:

| Name | Alignment | Patron of | Editions | Connection to the sea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Deep Sashelas](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Sashelas) | Chaotic Good | Elves | 5e, 3e, 2e, 1e | Known as Lord of the Undersea, The Dolphin Prince, Sailor's Friend |
| [Persana](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Persana) | Neutral Good | Tritons | 2e | Created Tritons |
| [Sekolah](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Sekolah) | Lawful Evil | Sahuagin | 5e, 3e, 2e | Shark god |
| [Ulutiu](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ulutiu) | Lawful Neutral | arctic dwellers | 3e, 2e | Sails cold ocean on barge of ice |
| [Umberlee](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Umberlee) | Chaotic Evil | Anything sea related | 5e, 4e, 3e, 2e, 1e | Known as Great Queen of the Sea, Queen of the Depths, The Wavemother, Goddess of Oceans etc. |
| [Valkur](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Valkur) | Chaotic Good | sailors, ships, favorable winds, and naval combat | 5e, 4e, 3e, 2e, 1e | Known as Captain of the Waves |

That's all of the *directly* sea / ocean related deities I found in Forgotten Realms Wiki, and I couldn't find any other deity elsewhere. Note that while this Wiki is not a primary source, I did check sources linked there and as far as I can tell they are solid.